# Is it possible to restrict Self to unit structs in trait?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to restrict `Self` to unit structs in trait?

```rust
struct Error;
trait BadCreator
where
    Self: Sized, // <<< I would like to restrict Self to unit structs
{
    fn maybe_create_me(b: bool) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        match b {
            true => Ok(Self), // <<< This line doesn't compile
            false => Err(Error),
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found self type `Self`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:24
  |
8 |             true => Ok(Self),
  |                        ^^^^ not a value
  |
  = note: can't use `Self` as a constructor, you must use the implemented struct
```

I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
struct Foo;
impl BadCreator for Foo {}

let b: Foo = Foo::maybe_create_me(true)?;
```

Comment: what is a unit type for you ?

Comment: I edited the title. I meant unit struct, like `struct Foo;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible as of Rust 1.39.

---

Honestly, your question doesn't make sense to me. If you want to ensure that you can create a value without any parameters, *then require that* via a function that creates a value without any parameters:

```
trait BadCreator: Sized {
    fn create() -> Self;

    fn maybe_create_me(b: bool) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        match b {
            true => Ok(Self::create()),
            false => Err(Error),
        }
    }
}
```

Or use the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait:

```
trait BadCreator: Default {
    fn maybe_create_me(b: bool) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        match b {
            true => Ok(Self::default()),
            false => Err(Error),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Default` trait was exactly what I needed. Thanks.